# Trying to find what is the max number of processes I can open

Tags: c, unix

I am a total beginner in C.
I have this assginment to wirte a program that will find the max number of processes I can open.

I come out with this code:

```
int main() {

while (1){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid) {
        if ( pid == -1){
            fprintf(stderr,"Can't fork,error %d\n",errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else{
            int status;
            alarm(30);
            if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0)==pid) {
                alarm(0);
                // the child process complete within 30 seconds
                printf("Waiting.");
            }else {
                alarm(0);
                // the child process does not complete within 30 seconds
                printf("killed");
                kill(pid, SIGTERM);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        alarm(30);
        printf("child");
    }
}
}
```

The thing is this program caused my laptop to crash..:-|

I assumed that when the program will not be able to open more processes I will get -1 from the fork() and then will exit the program.
Well, it didn't happened.

Any idea?
What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: You are a beginner and you wrote this?! How familiar are you with programming in Unix?

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to know how many processes you can open you could use the sysconf call, looking for the _SC_CHILD_MAX variable. 
[Check here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sysconf.3.html).

Comment: This is probably the right way.. But I need to actually calculate it. The old fashion way.. with fork(), and in the end kill all the child processes that I have created

Answer (score 1):

U cannot "open" a process. You can *create* them.

**CHILD_MAX** is a constant that contains the value of max number of child processes that can be created. It is defined in *unistd.h* header. To query, use the `sysconf` function. Pass `CHILD_MAX` argument to `sysconf` with `_SC_` prefix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
     int res = sysconf(_SC_CHILD_MAX);
     if (res == -1) {
        perror("sysconf");
     } else {
        printf("The max number of processes that can be created is: %d\n", res);
     }

     return 0;
}
```